# Configure ERP conectivity to a Flex application via a web service

Tags: flex3

I am developing a Flex application that will need to 'pull' information from an ERP system such as SAP or Peoplesoft via the clients web service.

My application will need to pass credentials & query to a Query_URL and receive the returned data.  I saw a Flash Builder 4 presentation where the Adobe evangelist created a similar application using Twitter.

Insights or links to example code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[Tour de Flex](http://flex.org/tour) contains some examples for making SOAP and plain old XML Web Service requests (under Data Access).  This is the typical way that requests are made to a back-end ERP (or similar) system.